# DateFormat problem in pocket pc emulator

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, pocketpc

While converting a date value in a datatable such as "4/20/2011 7:10:39 PM" into a string by using ToString(),it becomes 4/20/11.How can i solve that problem?I want it as 4/20/2011.I am using Pocket Pc application in .net 2008 and using windows ce 5.0 emulator.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using along with the output and the output you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most actions on `DateTime` are supported by the .NET Compact Framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members(v=VS.90).aspx

You could use one of the built in ones, or one of the overrides of `ToString` and specify your own formatting arguments: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

The default action of `ToString` on `DateTime` takes into account the current culture of the process.

Try:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("d/MM/yyyy");`